# Get all controls from MasterPage ChildPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible to get all controls from a ChildPage from the MasterPage the child is nested in?

I need all the controls within my form tag, but when i use a MasterPage i cant see the controls from the ChildPage, only the ones in the MasterPage.

Anyone with a good solution on this one? :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a Label control as [Label1] on the child page.

So to access that child page control from the master page, i would use

Label lbl = (Label)this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("Label1");

lbl.Text = "I got you";

---

So to get all the controls simply do this:

**ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great article on some more advanced master page topics. I believe your situation is covered.

http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx